# html folder of file for input="file"

Tags: html, input, directory

This is for a Microsoft windows only solution. I am sure the answer is somewhere in `Scripting.FileSystemObject`.

In HTML I provide `input="file"` with id of inputfile.
Then, later, in java, I get the file using:

```
var selectedFile = document.getElementById('inputfile').files[0]
```

Now I need to create a new file in the same folder as the file provided by the user. Maybe my google search skills are just useless. I cannot figure this one out. I cannot get the folder path of the file specified by the user.

Comment: by java, you mean JavaScript, right?
[How is Java different from JavaScript](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: use the value

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

fso.GetParentFolderName(document.getElementById('inputfile').value);
```